# PHP - Create contact inside System Group: myContacts

Tags: google-contacts-api

I've a little question.

I want to create / update a contacts inside a system group,precisely myContacts group but unfortunately I can not.

This is my code:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
<atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
<gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>Surname</gd:givenName>
    <gd:familyName>Name</gd:familyName>
    <gd:fullName>Name Surname</gd:fullName>
</gd:name>
<gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" primary="true" address="firstemail@gmail.com" />
<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home">1234567891</gd:phoneNumber>
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/email@gmail.com/base/myContacts"/>
```

How I can create contact inside that system Group?

Comment: You can check the documentation about [updating contact groups](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#updating_contact_groups). It could be a big help. There are sample code snippets you needed. Also, take note that you need to secure a valid `userEmail` and `groupID` to start. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already read the docs but there is not anything about that. I want to create new contact inside system group myContacs, using Google Contacts api and not Google people api